# Schedule a time given but works with different time zones in SQL Server and using Java client

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I need to allow a system to schedule some time locally and present this time correctly in different time zones.

So if I schedule a time between 1pm to 3pm in United Kingdom, then if I was to see this schedule in America, then as you know America is 7 hours ahead and so Americas schedule time would be 7pm to 10pm

I have used datetimeoffset in sql server before which allows UTC dates to work with different time zones.

And I really need to use sql server for this solution.

So how would I go about this approach to get time differences when a user selects the start date and end date?

The client side I will be using is java to display the start and end date for different time zones.

I have tried this in sql server but I used getutcdate. This was for another project to initialise when some date is stored initially wen a entry has been made. But like I said above I need users to select date between the start date and end date.

Just to note the database that stores the date is 1 hour ahead as it's on a server in another country.

Comment: Store your dates as UTC dates, and display them using the users locale? And convert from local user time to UTC before storing in the database.

Comment: Use a [`java.time.ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) on the Java side. Convert between UTC and the [time zone of the user](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) when communicating with the database. Or find a way to store the time zone in the database. Also, just in case, note that a _time zone_ is not the same thing as an _offset_.

Comment: Store the timezone with the date/time value! Converting the time to UTC is only the second best solution, because when you want to run something at nine o'clock walltime, this should not change when DST is switched on or off. And as said alread by @Slaw, there is an important distinction between timezone (Europe/London), an offset (+00:00) and a zone time (GMT). You need to store the timezone!!!

Comment: If your politicians were to change the rules of your time zone, such as adopting or dropping Daylight Saving Time (DST), would you want the time-of-day to change accordingly? Or would you want to stick with the same moment, the same point on the timeline regardless of what rules are changed by the politicians?

Comment: Thanks @DaleK and Slaw, tquadrat and basil bourque for the quick response. What would be the datatype in sql server 2019 that would need to select from

Comment: _"So if I shedule a time between 1pm to 3pm in United Kingdom, then if I was to see this schedule in America, then as you know America is 7 hours infront and so Americas shedule time would be 7pm to 10pm"_ - No, the offset is _behind_ (negative) and there are 4 timezones in the continental US, and the offset also depends on Daylight Saving time, which isn't uniformly observed.  A real mess.

Comment: Another wrinkle: Say I scheduled a meeting for 2023-11-03 09:30:00 GMT in London.  On the west coast of the US that falls into the DST change time, complicating the issue even more.  Handling dates/times/zones correctly is incredibly complex and prone to errors.  The only sane solution is to store all dates/time as UTC (zero offset) and convert to/from local for the user interface.

Comment: Would I need to write something so when a user selects the start and end date, I would need to manually set the correct time zones individually for every country to get the correct time zones

Comment: No, convert ONLY on input (from the user's locale to UTC) and on output (from UTC to the user's locale).  A user's local time can always be unambiguously converted to UTC, and a given UTC instant can always be converted to a local time in any timezone.

Comment: What data type needs to be selected in sql server 2019, its not datetimeoffset as its been mentioned in this post. So what would be the datatype I select in sql server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255887/discussion-between-redoc01-and-jim-garrison).

Comment: Voting to reopen because (a) The subject is HARD for developers to get right, even if the question was a bit unfocused, but more importantly (b) The answer from @BasilBourque is pretty much canonical for the topic and needs to be preserved.

Comment: If this question is to be preserved then please fix the 2nd paragraph.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have not specified if you want to track a specific point on the timeline or if you want to track a time-of-day that adjusts as needed if politicians change the rules of your time zone. The first case (like a rocket launch) is simpler, but I get the sense you meant the second case (like booking a medical/dental appointment). Let's cover both.

### Fixed point in time

To schedule a rocket launch, the flight engineers study the weather predictions. Once they pick an opportune launch time, that point on the time line is fixed, unchanging. If politicians change the rules for the time zone, the launch does not move. The planned moment remains the same even though the wall clock time in the surrounding area may change from 15:33 to 14:33. The weather, and the rocket, don't care about the time-of-day, they care about a point on the timeline.

If you are tracking specific point on the timeline, use the standard SQL type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. In [MS SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server), that would be the type [`datetimeoffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). In Java, use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) in general, but for [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) database calls, use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

| Kind of data | Standard SQL | MS SQL Server | Java |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Point on time line | `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` | [`datetimeoffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) | Generally use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html). In JDBC, use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html). |
| Duration | `VARCHAR` | [`varchar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#varchar---n--max--) | [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) |

Say our rocket launch flight director has determined a launch time of 3:33 PM on January 23rd, 2024 as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from the temporal meridian of UTC. In standard ISO 8601 text, that would be `2024-01-23T15:33:00Z`. The `Z` on the end indicates an offset of zero, and is pronounced “Zulu”.

The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating text.

```
Instant launchWindowStart = Instant.parse( "2024-01-23T15:33:00Z" ) ;
```

And imagine that the launch window is one hour long. We use Duration class to represent that span of time unattached to the timeline.

```
Duration launchWindowSpan = Duration.ofHours( 1 ) ;
```

We can determine the end time:

```
Instant launchWindowEnd = launchWindowStart.plus( launchWindowSpan ) ;
```

In our database we could store either the start and the span, or the start and the end, or all three (though all three would violate [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)). For JDBC, adjust the `Instant` objects into `OffsetDateTime` as the SQL standard has no concept mapping to `Instant`.

```
OffsetDateTime odtLaunchWindowStart = launchWindowStart.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
OffsetDateTime odtLaunchWindowEnd = launchWindowEnd.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;

myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odtLaunchWindowStart ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setString( … , launchWindowSpan.toString() ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odtLaunchWindowEnd ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
Instant launchWindowStart = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class).toInstant() ;
Duration launchWindowSpan = Duration.parse( myResultSet.getString() ) ;
Instant launchWindowEnd = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class).toInstant() ;
```

### Moving point in time

For appointments, you need to store the date & time-of-day separately from the intended time zone. So two columns in your table.

For date & time-of-day in MS SQL Server, use `datetime2` type. In Java, [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

For the time zone, store the [`Continent/Region`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) name of the zone such as `Europe/London`. In Java, [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html).

Record appointments only with a start time, not a stop time. Instead of a stop time, store a *duration*. The stop time may not be the time-of-day you expect. For example, if an appointment starts at 1 PM but happens to occur during a "spring-ahead" clock cutover, the stop time might be 4 PM rather than the 3 PM you would otherwise expect so a 2-hour meeting could run 1-4 PM.

Neither the SQL Standard nor MS SQL Server offers a data type for duration. So store as text in standard ISO 8601 format. For duration in the database, store as text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format of `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where `P` marks the beginning, and the `T` separates the years-months-days from the hours-minutes-seconds. For Java, use [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) object. A duration of two hours is `PT2H`.

| Kind of data | Standard SQL | MS SQL Server | Java |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Date + time-of-day | `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` | [`datetime2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#datetime2-description) | [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) |
| Time zone name | `VARCHAR` | [`varchar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#varchar---n--max--) | [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) |
| Duration | `VARCHAR` | [`varchar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#varchar---n--max--) | [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) |

> shedule a time between 1pm to 3pm in United Kingdom

As an example, let's book a week out from today.

```
ZoneId zLondon = ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zLondon ) ;
LocalDate apptDate = today.plusWeeks( 1 ) ;
LocalTime apptTime = LocalTime.of( 13 , 0 ) ;  // 1 PM.
LocalDateTime apptStart = LocalDateTime.of( apptDate , apptTime ) ;
Duration duration = Duration.ofHours( 2 ) ;
```

Write those to your `datetime2`, `VARCHAR`, and `VARCHAR` columns.

```java
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , apptStart ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setString( … , zLondon.toString() ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setString( … , duration.toString() ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```java
LocalDateTime apptStart = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
ZoneId zLondon = ZoneId.of( myResultSet.getString( … ) ) ;
Duration duration = Duration.parse( myResultSet.getString( … ) ) ;
```

Be very clear on this crucial point: `LocalDateTime` & `datetime2` do *not* represent a moment, are *not* a point on the timeline. They represent merely a date with a time-of-day. They purposely lack any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So their values are inherently ambiguous.

When it comes time to build a schedule, apply the time zone to the date-time. Very important: **Do *not* store this value**, use it only to build a schedule dynamically, temporarily, such as for presentation to the user.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtLondon = appt.atZone( zLondon ) ;
```

Now we have a moment, a specific point on the timeline.

You can adjust to another time zone.

```java
ZoneId zEdmonton = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtEdmonton = zdtLondon.atZoneSameInstant( zEdmonton ) ;
```

Both `zdtLondon` and `zdtEdmonton` represent the same simultaneous moment, the same point on the timeline. The one single moment is being viewed through two different lenses, the lens of the wall clock & calendar used by people in England UK versus the lens of the wall clock and calendar used by the people of Alberta Canada.

Spans of time are generally best handled using the Half-Open approach. In Half-Open, the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So an appoint from 1 PM to 3 PM starts at the first moment of the hour 13, then runs up to, but does not include, the first moment of the hour 15 (or so, depending on political time-keeping anomalies mentioned above). Tip: In SQL, do *not* use `BETWEEN` in your Half-Open queries, as `BETWEEN` is Fully Closed (both start and end are inclusive).

To represent the whole span of time, the *java.time* framework does not define any such class. You could define your own. For example:

```
record SpanOfTimeZoned ( ZonedDateTime start , ZonedDateTime end ) {}
```

Or more practical:

```java
public record SpanOfTimeZoned( ZonedDateTime start , ZonedDateTime end ) {
    public static SpanOfTimeZoned of ( ZonedDateTime start , Duration duration ) {
        return new SpanOfTimeZoned ( start , start.plus ( duration ) );
    }

    public Duration duration ( ) {
        return Duration.between ( this.start , this.end );
    }
}
```

Usage:

```java
SpanOfTimeZoned apptSpan = SpanOfTimeZoned.of( zdtEdmonton , duration ) ;
```

Or, you might find useful adding the [ThreeTen-Extra](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. That library offers the [`Interval`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class, holding a pair of [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) objects. An `Instant` represents a moment as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from the temporal meridian of UTC.

```
Interval apptSpan = Interval.of( zdtEdmonton.toInstant() , duration ) ;
```

Note that `org.threeten.extra.Interval` is always in UTC (an offset of zero), not a particular time zone. You can, of course, always apply a time zone to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime apptStartLondon = apptSpan.getStart().atZone( zLondon ) ;
```

You said:

> The clientside I will be using is java to display the start and end date for different time zones.

In your app, you need to collect from the user:

- Date
- Start time
- Time zone
- Duration (or calculate based on user providing an end-time)

From that, you will produce in Java:

- `LocalDateTime` object
- `ZoneId` object
- `Duration` object

Sounds like you want to convert from the user's time zone to your preferred time zone before storing in the database. Be aware that this conversion is risky. We can adjust from Edmonton time to London time, for example. But that adjustment must use the rules for both those zones as they exist at this moment. In the time between this moment and that appointment, if politicians in Alberta, or politicians in England, were to change their time zone rules, our stored appointment will appear to be wrong from the perspective of the person on the other side of the pond. This change by politicians may seem unlikely; history has proved otherwise. Politicians around the world have shown a penchant for twiddling with the time zone rules of their jurisdiction.

```java
LocalDateTime userLdt = LocalDateTime.of( … ) ;
ZoneId userZoneId = ZoneId.of( … ) ;
Duration duration = Duration.of( … ) ;

ZonedDateTime userZdt = userLdt.atZone( userZoneId ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtLondon = userZdt.atZoneSameInstant( zLondon ) ;
LocalDateTime apptStart = zdtLondon.toLocalDateTime() ;
```

At this point you can store `apptStart`, `zLondon`, and `duration` as discussed earlier in this Answer.

Comment: Why varchar for duration?

Comment: @DaleK Because neither the SQL Standard nor MS SQL Server offers a data type for duration. So store  as text in standard ISO 8601 format. The SQL Standard barely touches on date-time matters, and even that they did poorly.

Comment: One should just watch out so sql server doesn't re-mangle localdatetimes into it's own local version of datetime2. Dating is very hard indeed, nice answer!

Comment: Great answer! I have also voted to open the question because it does not deserve to be closed.