# What is the SQL Server Database column type for java.time.OffsetDateTime?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, azure-sql-database, java-time

We are trying to map `OffsetDateTime` in Java and insert into SQL Server, using `JDBCTemplate`. Our customers are in multiple different time zones around the world.

What is the proper SQL Server / Azure SQL data column type for OffsetDateTime? I didn't see it in chart here . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-basic-data-types?view=sql-server-ver16

```
using java.time.OffsetDateTime

private OffsetDateTime purchaseDate;
```

I am thinking MS SQL `datetimeoffset`, however the table is displaying Java type as `microsoft.sql.DateTimeOffset`, not `java.time.OffsetDateTime` .

However, using `datetimeoffset` in SQL seems to work with `java.time.OffsetDateTime`, just want to be sure.

[image]

Comment: can you send me link or official docs? I may close this question, there is so much vague and disagreeing internet posts about this topic, @DaleK , feel free to post answer and I can send points, thanks

Comment: Hilarious! We need to be specific but the OffsetDateTime type documentation defines it as relative to UTC/Greenwich time?  UTC/Greenwich are not the same thing (thanks to atomic clocks UTC drifts from Greenwich which is mean solar time), so what measure is OffsetDateTime even representing?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning The *java.time* framework defines its own time-scale, the *Java Time-Scale*. See documentation on the Javadoc of [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/time/Instant.html) class. For the purposes of business apps commonly built by Java developers, there is no practical difference between GMT, UTC, and The Java Time-Scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

| Kind of data | Standard SQL | MS SQL Server | Java |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Point on time line | `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` | [`datetimeoffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) | In [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity), use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html). Outside of JDBC, generally best to use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) or [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). |

To represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline, use the SQL standard type of `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. In [Microsoft SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) that type maps to [`datetimeoffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Java offers three classes to represent a point on the timeline:

- `java.time.Instant`
- `java.time.OffsetDateTime`
- `java.time.ZonedDateTime`

The first represents a moment as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from the temporal meridian of UTC. The second is similar but can have an offset of any number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead/behind UTC. The third one contains a time zone, which is a named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region as decided by their politicians.

The SQL standard barely touches on date-time matters, and does so poorly. The standard lacks the concepts captured in the `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime` classes. So [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) maps only the `OffsetDateTime` class to a column of the type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

---

As for your chart, I’ve no idea what is going on. That chart seems to be referencing this class, [microsoft.sql.Types.DATETIMEOFFSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/reference/datetimeoffset-class?view=sql-server-ver16). That class appears to be part of Microsoft’s JDBC driver. But Microsoft defining their own class mapped in JDBC makes no sense as that class would be incompatible with JDBC-compliant programs. I’m not a Microsoft customer, so I cannot provide an explanation.

Comment: nice, where did you get the reference? you seem to have [2] [4],  also are you saying in JDBC, use offsetDateTime, and in others like JPA use Instance? thanks

Comment: @mattsmith5 (a) I copied from [an Answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77449976/642706) that I wrote yesterday. (b) No, I am not saying that. JPA (now [*Jakarta Persistence*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/)) is built on top of JDBC. So the SQL-Java mappings in JDBC apply there.